# Lógica promisses ou callback com SweetAlert e VueJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, lógica, sweetalert

Estou a tentar fazer uma callback para executar algumas funções, eu não sei se devo utilizar promisses, callbacks ou algo mais avançado. Esse problema se trata mais de lógica

Eu possuo um Mixin que dispara o Alerta

**sweetalertMixin**

```
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        sweetAlert(mensagem){
            this.$swal({
                title: 'Você tem certeza?',
                text: mensagem,
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Confirmar',
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
            }).then(function(confirmado) {
                return true
            }, function(cancelado) {
                return false
            })

        }
    }
})
```

**crud.js**

```
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {

DeletarTudo(url){
    // Executa isso primeiro para minha variável receber valor
    let sweetAlertBoolean = this.sweetAlert("Deletar Tudo?") 

    // Depois executa esse IF   
    if(sweetAlertBoolean){
        // Faça algo
    } else{
        // Faça algo
    }
}

RecuperarTudo(url){
    // Executa isso primeiro para minha variável receber valor
    let sweetAlertBoolean = this.sweetAlert("Recuperar Tudo?") 

    // Depois executa esse IF   
    if(sweetAlertBoolean){
        // Faça algo
    } else{
        // Faça algo
    }
}
}
```

E no meu arquivo **.vue** na parte de scripts tenho meus methods

```
methods: {
    botaoRecuperar: function() {
        this.RecuperarTudo("/Recuperar")
    },
    botaoExcluir: function() {
        this.DeletarTudo("/Deletar")
    }
}
```

Estes return true/false que atribuo ao meu `sweetAlertBoolean` não fazem nada. 
Como faço para minha minha variável `sweetAlertBoolean` ser atribuída antes de executar o `if` abaixo dela?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em vez de pensares em `if`/`else` assíncrono pensa que o `then` recebe uma função `if` e outra `else`.

Ou seja essa lógica está no código do `mixin` em forma de promise, e o que deves fazer é chamar outros métodos dentro dessas funções que façam o que queres. No teu caso só precisas usar o caso afirmativo, então podes simplificar para:

```
}).then(() => this.funcaoApagar());
```

Comment: Tentei deixar a pergunta com menos código possível, acabou não dando certo... Este meu mixin `sweetAlert` eu vou usar em vários lugares, eu poderia copiar e colar o mesmo código dentro dos meu `methods` DeletarTudo e RecuperarTudo e então utilizar os callbacks nativos do plugin **Sweetalert**, mas estou a separar em um mixin para ter menos código

Comment: Se queres ter mais controlo sobre o que acontece podes passar esses métodos no momento que chamas o `sweetAlert` assim `sweetAlert(mensagem, function(){/* caso A */}, function(){/* caso B */}){` e depois passas essa funções à promise.

Comment: @Jackson ^ faz sentido?

Comment: Faz sim Sergio, mas acaba ficando um código muito complicado de se analisar..Não existe alguma outra maneira de solucionar este caso? Eu poderia por exemplo colocar um `setTimeout` verificando `if(sweetAlertBoolean==undefined) { // faça nada } else { //executa meu código lá da pergunta  } ... Mas isso é muito feio

Comment: @Jackson é feio e é impossivel saber quanto tempo o utilizador demora a clicak OK :) Porque dizes que fica complicado de analizar? O que podes fazer é dar `return` dentro desse método. Ficar `return this.$swal({` e assim ficas com a promise no sitio do `if`/`else`. Essa é talvez a maneira mais limpa.

Comment: Perfeito Sergio, vou aplicar esta tua solução! Obrigado ;) !